# WebAPI / Owin - Identity is not authorized after signing-in

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing simple login/password authentication using WebAPI/Owin 3.0. Here is my config method:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
    // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/#sign-in")
    });
}
```

Here is Login method

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
public class AccountController : ApiController {

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Login(LoginBindingModel login) {
        ApplicationUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(login.Email, login.Password);
        if(user != null) {
            var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);        
            Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, identity);
            return Ok("OK");
        }

        return BadRequest("Invalid email or password");
    }

}
```

I can see authentication cookie coming from the server after I send a request to the Login method. I also see that the cookie is sent back to the server when sending further requests. However, the server returns 401 Unauthorized response.

I put a breakpoint into the AuthorizeAttribute.IsAuthorized method. It turned out that 
actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false because AuthenticationType is null and there are no claims. Original identity in the Login method had 4 claims and its IsAuthenticated property was true.

Why does the Identity loses all its Claims and AuthenticationType values?

I'm testing using local IISExpress server with app running on localhost domain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turned out that Cookie authentication conflicts with SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication option. Disable this in WebApiConfig.cs to solve the problem.

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

Comment: I was aware of this at some point in my past but this haunted me for 2 hours yesterday until I found this post.