# Authorization with ASP.NET Identity & Autofac OWIN integration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin, autofac

*(an update has been added at the bottom of this question)*

I have a web application that uses both MVC5 and WebAPI2 with Autofac for DI. The app uses ASP.NET Identity and oAuth bearer tokens, though the latter may be beside the point. This has all worked perfectly well, but at this point I need the same instances of my injected services to be shared throughout the OWIN pipeline as well as the rest of my application and therefore I'm trying to setup Autofac's OWIN integrations for MVC and Web API. I seem to be close- everything seems to work except for `AuthorizeAttibutes` on `ApiControllers`. The oAuth process completes successfully and I end up signed in with a bearer token, but subsequent attempts to authorize with said token on WebAPI controllers/actions fail.

Specifically, in the `IsAuthorized` method of `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, `IPrincipal.Identity` seems that it has not been instantiated correctly in that it doesn't have the appropriate claims and the `IsAuthenticated` property is always false. The developers of Autofac indicate that [this attribute should work with the OWIN integrations](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/509), even though that code uses `GlobalConfiguration` [which is not advisable for the OWIN integrations](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration). I've seen multiple recommendations to remove `config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785528/user-iprincipal-not-avaliable-on-apicontrollers-constructor-using-web-api-2-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294032/webapi-owin-identity-is-not-authorized-after-signing-in)), which, while not advisable, I've tried out of desperation and yet to no avail- for my particular configuration this causes IPrincipal to come back as null. I've also tried to modify [a much simpler example project](https://github.com/AkosLukacs/Autofac-OWIN-MVC) than my own to use `AuthorizeAttribute` on the WebAPI controller, also with no success. At this point I'm out of things to try, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof (Startup))]
namespace Project.Web
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(config);
            builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            RegisterGeneralTypes(builder);
            var container = builder.Build();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
            WebApiFilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(config.Filters);

            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
            app.UseAutofacMvc();
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        private static void RegisterGeneralTypes(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(c => new DomainModelContext())
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User.Identity)
                .As(typeof (IIdentity));

            builder.RegisterType<EmailService>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<DomainUserManager>
            {
                DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider
            }).InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<DomainUserManager>()
                .AsSelf()
                .UsingConstructor(typeof (IIdentityMessageService),
                    typeof (IdentityFactoryOptions<DomainUserManager>),
                    typeof (CustomUserStore))
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.RegisterType<CustomUserStore>()
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerRequest();

            builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication)
                .As<IAuthenticationManager>();
        }
    }
}
```

and my Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    internal static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider;
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }
    public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var onValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
            .OnValidateIdentity<DomainUserManager, DomainUser, int>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                    user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType),
                getUserIdCallback: id => id.GetUserId<int>());

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),

            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = onValidateIdentity
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/v1/account/externallogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

        DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider();
    }
}
```

I think that covers it, but I will gladly post additional code upon request.

**UPDATE**

So based on [jumuro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826551/authorization-with-asp-net-identity-autofac-owin-integration/37839448#37839448), I changed my order of registrations as recommended. However, this simply transferred the exact same issue from Web API authorization to MVC authorization. Since I had MVC auth working before the update, I ultimately tried registering auth in the pipeline twice as follows:

```
app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
ConfigureAuth(app);
app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
app.UseAutofacMvc();
app.UseWebApi(config);
ConfigureAuth(app);
```

This works, but I really can't say that I understand why and I can't imagine that it's good to be doing this twice. So now I have new questions:

1. It makes sense that WebAPI would need Auth registered in the
   pipeline first, but why in the world does MVC want me to register
   Auth *last*?
2. How can I clean this up and avoid calling `ConfigureAuth` twice?

Comment: So what happens? Do you get an error? Can you post the error message?

Comment: @NightOwl888 like I said, IPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated always comes back as false, so Authorization fails and a 404 response is returned to the client. Nothing blows up, the IPrincipal just doesn't seem to be getting instantiated correctly. In terms of the specifics, it behaves almost exactly as one of the [links I posted above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294032/webapi-owin-identity-is-not-authorized-after-signing-in). However, in my case removing config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication() causes IPrincipal to become null.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add middlewares to the application pipeline in the correct order. Bearer token has to be validated before the MVC and Web Api middlewares process the request.

Try this order in your `Configuration()` method:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ...
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.UseAutofacMvc();
    app.UseWebApi(config);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    ...
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: So close! This fixes the problem in WebAPI, but causes the exact same problem to present itself in MVC.

Comment: The same `ConfigureAuth()` method was working for MVC and Web Api before adding Autofac?

Comment: The same `ConfigureAuth()` was working for MVC and Web API with Autofac before adding the OWIN integrations for Autofac. The OWIN integrations are what started to cause the issues at hand.

Comment: You may need to look deeper inside the lifecycles to understand this behaviour. Until this occurs and to avoid repeat code you could try to split your `ConfigureAuth()` method in `ConfigureAuthMvc()` and `ConfigureAuthWebApi()` and call each one in the order you need.

Comment: I had actually considered that, but I'm still pretty confounded as to why MVC wants the auth configured *after* its middleware has been registered in the OWIN pipeline. I just can't wrap my head around that. I've got a discussion going with Travis Illig of the Autofac team regarding this, so if he has time to provide insight, I'll reflect what I learn here.

Comment: I'd love you share the explanation of the behaviour if you find out, thanks.